# Application database file is of size 0 bytes in Android?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-file

I am trying to save a backup of database to sdcard. I am trying to get the file at the below location:

/data/data/{package_name}/databases/database.db

But the size of the file is returned to be zero. Please let me know what could be the problem. Thank you for your advice and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think there is a problem of extenstion **/data/data/{package_name}/databases/database.db**
write **/data/data/{package_name}/databases/database.sqlite**

Comment: But when I check for file.exists(), it returns true. When I try database.sqlite if get false.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. You were right that the extension could be the problem. When creating the db i created with the name without any extension. So when i used database instead database.db things worked fine for me. Thank you very much.